# Транзакционная модель

Tags: c++, mysql, innodb

В рамках многопоточного приложения работа с БД осуществляется посредством использования одной и той же учётной записи. Каждый поток имеет отдельное соединение с БД. Появилась необходимость использовать транзакции.

В официальной документации мне не удалось обнаружить (буду признателен за ссылку), где бы чётко оговаривалось, что транзакционная модель в `InnoDb` функционирует и на уровне соединений, а не только на уровне отдельных учётных записей. Возможно, что это априори, однако я некомпетентен в рассматриваемой области. Хотелось бы, по возможности, получить точный ответ.

Второй вопрос вытекает из первого. Если транзакционная модель `InnoDb` всё же реализована на уровне отдельных соединений, то существует ли также возможность создавать отдельные, но параллельно выполняемые транзакции в рамках одного и того же соединения в одном и том же потоке? Это, скажем, может понадобиться при асинхронном выполнении. К сожалению, в документации я не увидел возможности указывать транзакциям какие-либо уникальные имена или идентификаторы.

MySQL 5.7

Comment: А почему именно в рамках одного соединения? Почему бы не открыть два параллельных соединения?

Comment: @cheops, я просто спросил о возможности открытия нескольких транзакций при использовании одного и того же соединения. Приложение построено с использованием фреймворка `Qt`, и там очень удобно именно когда соединение глобальное на поток, т.к. в обратном случае приходится вставлять дополнительные обёртки, следящее за тем, чтобы закрыть соединение тогда, когда оно перестало быть необходимым.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Транзакционная модель функционирует, как ни странно, на уровне транзакций - группы команд между `begin` и `commit`/`rollback` (одиночные запросы вне открытой явно транзакции автоматически оборачиваются в транзакцию, без транзакции транзакционные хранилища не работают). В рамках одного соединения может быть много транзакций. От одного пользователя может быть много одновременных и независимых соединений, и, следовательно, конкурентных транзакций тоже может быть много. В сущности, в понятии транзакции нет ни соединения, ни пользователя. Есть только id транзакции, согласно которому вычисляется видимость актуальных версий строк в `MVCC` и за которым закрепляются взятые блокировки.

В известных мне СУБД - `mysql` и `postgresql` - одно соединение одновременно держать две разные транзакции открытыми не может, одно соединение - только одна открытая транзакция. И не припоминаю возможности в рамках одного соединения выполнять одновременно несколько команд. Библиотека может предоставлять неблокирующий вызов, но не дождавшись конца ответа новые запросы отправлять не получится.

Comment: Под асинхронностью я подразумевал асинхронность именно на стороне приложения, а не БД. То есть, допустим, сначала открытие одной транзакции в одной функции и выполнение в ней же некоего запроса. Затем открытие другой транзакции в другой функции и выполнение другого запроса. Затем снова возвращаемся к первой транзакции и выполняем запрос, ну и т.д. Всё это однопоточно, друг за другом. Но при этом тогда получается, что раз уж нет возможности указать, какой запрос к какой транзакции относится, то БД не сможет эту ситуацию разрулить. Я правильно Вас понял?

Comment: Да, для этого поведения вам придётся открывать несколько соединений. Тогда транзакции смогут быть открытыми одновременно. Да и сами команды можно будет отправлять параллельно. И, если только они не подерутся за блокировки, то они реально будут исполняться параллельно.

Answer (score 5):

В MySQL каждый тред держит соединение. Он не отслеживает, каким процессом это соединение открыто, т.е. ему без разницы, один процесс открыл кучу соединений или это куча процессов.

MySQL выполняет запросы параллельно, в рамках тредной модели, но существуют блокировки:

на уровне MySQL в целом:

- на метаданные
- транзакционные

на уровне движка (InnoDb)

- на таблицы, в случае индексации, оптимизации
- счетчик автоинкремента

на таблицу

- в случае записи на строки
- LOCK TABLE
- полный скан таблицы (индексация)

В случае транзакций:
После того как стартует транзакция - происходят какие-то изменения данных, которые пишутся в журнал, далее мы эти изменения коммитим или отменяем. Как только мы выполнили эти изменения, то они из журнала переходят в данные. На время выполнения транзакции - данные используемой табл доступны для чтения (но это зависит от уровня изоляции транзакции).

В рамках одного соединения может стартовать только одна транзакция. COMMIT закрепляет транзакцию.

Советую книгу [**MySQL. «Оптимизация производительности»**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9780596101718%2C+9785932861530&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0), там очень хорошо расписано про блокировки и транзакции.